# Channel form: multiple entries

Tags: safecracker, ee4

What would be the best way to create multiple entries?

In short: I'm working on a website where an entry always contains 1 image. No more, no less. An entry without an image can't be published. All entries have exactly one image.

The (html5) input tag. I can create a (channel) form where a user is able to upload multiple images via drag and drop or via

```
<input type="file" multiple>
```

I would like to create a new entry for each file. What would be the best way to create multiple entries?

Can I send the files somewhere (AJAX) and create a new entry based on the file?